# VS Codeで開始と終わりの<>を四角く囲まれる挙動を無効化したい

Tags: html5, vscode

VScodeで開始と終わりの<>を四角く囲まれる挙動が見にくいため、
無効化したいのですが、アドバイスいただけますと幸いです。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

対応する括弧が正しく閉じられているかを強調する機能だと思いますので、設定 (Setting.json) で
以下の通り "editor.matchBrackets" を無効 (false) にしてみてください。

[How to disable angle bracket highlighting in Visual Studio Code? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45301283/2322778) での [回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45301690/2322778) より:

```js
"editor.matchBrackets": false
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。バッチリでした